# Add bulk of users in gitlab using gitlabapi

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am able to add a single user using Gitlabapi but, I need to add many users so Is there any possibility to add bulk of users at a time to Gitlab project using Gitlabapi. And while creating users, role and the group should be assigned as well.
I am using node.js for implementing this. Is there any library in node.js to do all these functionalities???

I found one library(i.e, gitlab) in node.js but with that I can able to fetch users, projects and create projects but am not able to create users

Answer (score 0):

No you can't create multiple users at once as per the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html API accepts user id as a part of URI. To reduce the time to create multiple users you can try doing it in a parallel requests.